# Is there a way to view the actual XML produced and received by the xmlrpc-c library?

Tags: xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I've got a system where some C++ code (using xmlrpc-c) talks to a Java servlet which uses the Apache XML-RPC library.

I've got a problem that would be a whole lot easier to resolve if I could view the actual XML being sent back and forth. Is there some way to turn on logging of the wire protocol XML in either Apache XMLRPC or xmlrpc-c?

Comment: You can try [tcpmon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do it on the C++ side. If you define the environment variable `XMLRPC_TRACE_XML` before running your xmlrpc-c code, it logs all XML received and sent and sends it to stderr.

See [The xmlrpc-c docs](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/doc/libxmlrpc_server++.html#trace_xml) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the logging part, but if the library you're using lets you specify a proxy, you could direct it to a web debugger like Fiddler, and see the output there.

Another possibility is to use a network sniffer tool like WireShark. It has a "follow conversation" feature that makes it easy to see the content of multiple packets.